# Can I bypass cloudflare?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can I bypass cloudflare or use another method from  [this](https://cs.money/load_bots_inventory?hash=1521882790699) page
My code:

index.js:

```
const request = require('request');

request('https://cs.money/load_bots_inventory?hash=1521879336025', { 
json:true }, (err, res, body) => { 

if (err) { return console.log(err); }
console.log(body);
  console.log(body.explanation);
});
```

server.js

```
const http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// file is included here:
eval(fs.readFileSync('index.js')+'');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Node.js');
}).listen(3000, () => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: where is cloudflare?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: on the console if I trying to do get request and display body

Comment: Nico, I want to parse JSON from page

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I assume that you don't control the `cs.money` domain.

Based on this, I don't think you can find out what the origin server is. Also, the owners of `cs.money` use cloudflair for a specific reason and probably don't want you to do this. Chances are that what you're trying to do is against the terms of use of the website you're trying to game.

Comment: Last sentence was my very first thought when I read the question.